# Maximum value of $\frac{\alpha\overline{\beta}+\overline{\alpha}\beta}{|\alpha\beta|}$

Tags: complex-numbers

Maximum value of  $$\frac{\alpha\overline\beta+\overline\alpha\beta}{|\alpha\beta|}$$ is

1) 2

2) 1

3) none of the above.

Considering $\alpha=x+iy$ and $\beta=m+in$ , on evaluating the expression I got $\frac{2.(xm+ny)}{\sqrt{(x^{2}+y^{2})(m^{2}+n^{2})}}$ which is $\leq \frac{2.(xm+ny)}{\sqrt{4xymn}}$. Least value of this is 2. So can we call it as maximum value ?

Comment: Your title is not very informative. Please [read this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/145141) to learn how to write good titles.

Comment: See also: [Proving an identity relating to the complex modulus: $z\bar{a}+\bar{z}a \leq 2|a||z|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2310666)

Answer (score 2):

To show that $2$ is possible to obtain, let $\alpha = \beta = 1$.

For all other values of $\alpha, \beta$, the triangle inequality gives 
$$
|\alpha\bar \beta + \bar \alpha\beta| \leq |\alpha\bar\beta|+|\bar\alpha\beta|
$$
Can you finish from here?

Alternatively, let $\gamma = \alpha\bar\beta$. In that case, your fraction may be written as $\frac{\gamma + \bar \gamma}{|\gamma|}$. Now it should be easier to apply $\gamma = x + iy$ than it was when you had both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$\overline{\alpha}\beta+\alpha\overline{\beta}=2\text{Re}(\overline{\alpha}\beta)\le2|\overline{\alpha}\beta|=2|\alpha\beta|$$

where $\text{Re}$ means real part.